# Email Issue with Outlook

Tags: html, email, media-queries, newsletter

I have an issue when coding a block in Outlook.

I am trying to display only one block on desktop and one on mobile and have used classes and media queries. I know that for Outlook there are issues with media queries so this may be where I'm running into trouble.

Here's is my code which works fine in the browser, however, when I preview in Outlook it displays both the desktop and mobile version on top of each other when previewed in larger(desktop) version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <style type="text/css">

    @media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
        .mobile-hide {
            display:none !important;
            visibility:hidden !important;
            height:0 !important;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            font-size:0 !important;
            line-height:0 !important;
            padding:0;
            max-height:0;
            width:0 !important;
        }
        .mobile-show {
            display: block!important;
        }

    }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {

.desktop-hide{

    display:none;

    }

}

</style>
</head>



<body>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">


                                     <tr class="mobile-hide">
                                        <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td colspan="4" align="center">
                                            <p style="font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#393939;text-align:left;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;line-height:20px;font-weight: bold;">
    <span style="font-size:14px;color:white;padding:10px;background-color:lightblue;" bgcolor="lightblue">Test</span><br><br>
                                               <img style = "display: block!important;margin: 0 auto;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="left" style="padding:20px;">
                                            <p style="font-family:Verdana,sans-serif; color:#393939;text-align:left;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;line-height:20px;font-weight: bold;padding-left: :10px;">
                                                <h2>Test Your Page</h2>
                                                This is some test content to demonstrate the structure of how the page might be built. It is a test paragraph with a bit of content displayed and a smail bit of code attached.
                                            </p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="30" style="padding:10px;"><b>Right</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>


                                    <tr class = "desktop-hide">

                                        <td colspan="8">
                                            <table class="mobile-width" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr><td colspan ="2">Test Your Page <span style = "padding-left:30px;">Right</span></td></tr>
                                                <tr><td><img style = "display: block!important;margin: 0 auto;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></td><td>This is some test content to demonstrate the structure of how the page might be built. It is a test paragraph with a bit of content displayed and a smail bit of code attached.</td></tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>



</table>



</body>
</html>
```

It would be great if someone can help me get this working so that when previewed in Outlook only one shows, depending on whether desktop or mobile view is showing

Comment: Why persist with meida queries in your email when support for it is patchy at best? https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/

Comment: thanks for responding, a lot of the detailed outline in this documentation seems to reference media queries. In relation to my code above, is it possible to suggest/edit it to perhaps get it working in Outlook so duplicate content doesn't show, thanks

Comment: The important part is the support table at the bottom. Outlook **does not support** media queries. I my opinion attempting to use media queries in email is currently a waste of time due to inconsistent support. Neither Outlook or the Gmail app support media queries, this is a massive amount of users.

Comment: Ok thanks Jon P, is it possible to suggest how I go about refactoring the above code, without media queries, so that the desktop row only show for desktop and the mobile row only shows for mobile, thanks

Comment: Your options would normally be media queries and we've discussed those, or javascript, which has even worse support. I *think* my answer could be the best compromise. When I have to do HTML emails, I tend to keep things a simple a possible, normally having to make a lot of compromises along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think trying to use a badly supported technology is folly, but the following *might* work.

Go mobile first. Apply the styles that will affect mobile **outside** of a media query. This means if media queries are not supported, this is your default style. Apply your desktop styles **inside** a media query, which should be ignored if media queries are not supported.

```css
/*Go Mobile First - This will happen if media queries are supported or not*/
  .mobile-hide {
    display: none;   
  }


/*This will work where supported and be ignored where not
  I.E. Outlook will always display the mobile version
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .desktop-hide {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .mobile-hide {
    display: table-row;   
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr class="mobile-hide">
    <td width="10">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
      <p style="font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#393939;text-align:left;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;line-height:20px;font-weight: bold;"><span style="font-size:14px;color:white;padding:10px;background-color:lightblue;" bgcolor="lightblue">Test</span><br><br><img style="display: block!important;margin: 0 auto;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></p>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" style="padding:20px;">
      <p style="font-family:Verdana,sans-serif; color:#393939;text-align:left;margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;line-height:20px;font-weight: bold;padding-left: :10px;">
        <h2>Test Your Page</h2>This is some test content to demonstrate the structure of how the page might be built. It is a test paragraph with a bit of content displayed and a smail bit of code attached. </p>
    </td>
    <td width="30" style="padding:10px;"><b>Right</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="desktop-hide">
    <td colspan="8">
      <table class="mobile-width" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">Test Your Page <span style="padding-left:30px;">Right</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><img style="display: block!important;margin: 0 auto;" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"></td>
          <td>This is some test content to demonstrate the structure of how the page might be built. It is a test paragraph with a bit of content displayed and a smail bit of code attached.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also avoid using `!important` in this case it will make media queries even harder to apply.